# Differences between gadget programming in Vista and Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, windows-desktop-gadgets

Besides the obvious fact that there's no sidebar in Windows 7, are there any differences in the way gadgets are put together? Anything I should look out for / resources I should read through?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370867(VS.85).aspx) covers the differences in gadgets in Vista and Windows 7.

I think primarily the issues you'll have to deal with are the IE 8 rendering engine and absence of the sidebar.  They cover in the article how they still handle the System.Gadget.onDock and System.Gadget.onUndock to maintain backward compatibility.